# Zeta zeros bug in Mathematica 12.0.0.0

Tags: bugs, evaluation, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 12.0.0 or earlier. Fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier.**

---

In Mathematica 12.0.0.0 when I input one of these:

```
Log[2/Im[ZetaZero[127]]]

Log[2/Im[ZetaZero[128]]]

Log[2/Im[ZetaZero[127]]]//N

Log[2/Im[ZetaZero[128]]]//N
```

notebook keeps running unevaluated forever. Notice that 127-th zeta zero is the first zero that violates the Gram's law ([Gram points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Gram_points)). So I guess this fact could have something to do with this bug. `Log[2/Im[ZetaZero[129]]]` is evaluated correctly.

Can you reproduce the bug? Is it the same with newer versions of Mathematica?

**EDIT:**

Better way to reproduce the bug:

Evaluate it on a fresh kernel - quit kernel, then type something simple like `2+2` to restart kernel and then type the code

```
Table[Log[Im[ZetaZero[n + 1]]/Im[ZetaZero[n]]], {n, 1, 128}] // N
```

It will keep running forever.

Comment: It evaluates instantly in ``"12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 24, 2021)"`` to $-4.95041$ and $-4.95305$.

Comment: Can you evaluate `Table[Log[Im[ZetaZero[n + 1]]/Im[ZetaZero[n]]], {n, 1, 128}] // N`. How long does it take on your version?

Comment: Evaluate it on a fresh kernel. Qiut kernel, then type something simple like `2+2` to restart kernel and then type the code with the table I posted above.

Comment: There must be some kind of bug. It is too slow anyway. And when I work with `ZetaZero` sometimes it keeps on evaluating forever when zero 127 or 128 occurs in my code.

Comment: When I tried it before, it took 13 seconds on the first run and 6 seconds for subsequent runs (probably because of some internal caching). However, on a fresh kernel, it does seem to get stuck!

Comment: I thought so... frustrating

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the hanging `Table` call in V12.3.

Comment: I reported this. Thank you @ChipHurst for the detailed analysis.

Comment: All command run fine in `13.2.0` on a mac; [**`see screenshot`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OM47.jpg)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Workaround:**

This issue seems to be related to caching of previous numerical values. If we clear the cache during each iteration we get a result back:

```
Table[
  ClearSystemCache["Numeric"]; 
  N[Log[Im[ZetaZero[n + 1]]/Im[ZetaZero[n]]]], 
  {n, 1, 128}
]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {6.8104, Null}
> ```

**What to do**

Report this to WRI.

It's strange that `N[ZetaZero[128]]` works, but iterating up to it in a `Table` breaks it.

**Diagnosis:**

After some investigation through `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions `` it seems we're getting stuck in an infinite `While` loop in `` System`FunctionZerosDump`NZetaZeroApprox ``.

The `While` loop is towards the bottom of the definition:

[image]

In our case, `m == 4969178850004113/17592186044416`, `p == ∞`, and hence `eps = 0`.

This makes our `While` loop spin forever, continually multiplying `2*0`.

**Offending call:**

The offending call is

```
System`FunctionZerosDump`NZetaZeroApprox[127, {∞, 16.255619765854984`}]
```

where `p` above is from `` System`FunctionZerosDump`NZetaZeroApprox[k, {p, a}] ``.

Changing `p` to something like `100` gives us a result.

Looking through `NValues` for `ZetaZero`, the only way `p` could be `∞` is if we make the call `N[ZetaZero[127], {∞, a}]` -- which we are not.

Comment: Thanks for detailed analysis. This bug persists in Mathematica from earlier versions. It was version 7 or 8 if I remember correctly when I started to use Mathematica, and the bug was already there. I even think that I reported this bug a long time ago but nothing happened. At least now I know how to avoid the bug - precompute values of required zeros and then use them instead of using `ZetaZero`.